# How do I enable history to record a here-document and its input?

Tags: bash, command-line, history, rxvt

When I use the command line I can recall history by using C-P or up arrow. However this does not work when trying to recall input to a here-document.

```
# cat <<!
> a
> b
> c
> !
a
b
c
# cat <<! # C-p to get here, expected to see ! as last input. C-c to break out
# history 2
2053  cat <<!
2054  history 2
```

I'm using rxvt.

P.S. This feature works correctly when using `shell` within `emacs`

Comment: You're right. The last command on the commandline was; "cat << !", thus, your can't recall the input to the 'program' cat. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have what sounds like the same problem. I was trying to pipe some SQL into a database client using here docs (psql <<EOF...) but everything after the EOF, on subsequent lines, (i.e the SQL, the valuable part) was not stored in my history.

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s cmdhist

cat <<!
a
b
c
!

history | tail ...
8580  cat <<!
a
b
c
!
```

> The **cmdhist** shell option, if enabled, causes the shell to attempt
>   to save each line of a        multi-line command  in the same history
>   entry, adding semicolons where necessary to preserve syntactic
>   correctness.
>
> The **lithist** shell  option causes the shell to save the command
>   with embedded newlines instead of semicolons.
>
> From man bash

Comment: `cmdhist` is already on - so no joy there. `lithist` was set off so I enabled it but again no success. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @user1077830: What shell are you using then? This doesn't work as you show in Bash 3.2.49.

Comment: I believe this was changed in 4.1 dev, and should work from 4.2. See Changelog line 9666 in bash-4.2 source. `cmdhist` should be set to keep all lines in one history entry, as described.

Comment: I came back to this question years later, and you are right - it now works for me in Bash 4.2 (although not perfectly - my history inserts a second newline between each line of the heredoc. Irksome but better than it was)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Bash 3.2.49(1)-release

```
psql <<EOF
SELECT * FROM blah;
EOF
```

My history only preserves the first line. I have got **cmdhist** (and **lithist**) set, and they work fine for other multi-line commands, but not for heredocs. Tragic.

A workaround is:

```
echo "
SELECT *
FROM blah
" | psql
```

Comment: As @mr.spuratic notes in a comment below, this seems to have been a bug that was fixed around Bash 4.2. Certainly it works somewhat better for me in Bash 4.2.46(2)-release. (Although not perfectly - it adds two newlines between each line of the heredoc, instead of just one.)